# How does this function for Hamming numbers work?

Tags: python

I was trying to write a function to generate Hamming numbers and encountered this code on [www.w3resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com).

The code is very easy but I can't seem to understand the order of output values.

```
def is_hamming_numbers(x):
    if x==1:
        return True
    if x%2==0:
        return is_hamming_numbers(x/2)
    if x%3==0:
        return is_hamming_numbers(x/3)
    if x%5==0:
        return is_hamming_numbers(x/5)
    return False

def hamming_numbers_sequence(x):
    if x==1:
        return 1
    hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1)
    if is_hamming_numbers(x)==True:
        print('%s'%x,end=' ')

hamming_numbers_sequence(10)
```

I expected the output to be:

```
10 9 8 8 5 4 3 2
```

The output would be:

```
2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10
```

Could anyone please explain why is the order of numbers reversed? I tried to change the order in the code like this:

```
if is_hamming_numbers(x)==True:
    print('%s'%x,end=' ') #this first
hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1) #then this line
```

And it would give the output in the order I expected.

Comment: beacuse your doing recursion the output is reversed it first does the last number
hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1) does it first  and then the rest so that is why it does reverse

Comment: `hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1)` creates a recursion so the firts number that is printed on the line `print('%s'%x,end=' ')` is 2 than 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
def hamming_numbers_sequence(x):
if x==1:
    return 1
hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1) // repeated here
if is_hamming_numbers(x)==True: // means x=2
    print('%s'%x,end=' ')
```

this function `hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1)` will repeat it self until reaching x=1 the blocking instruction `if x==1:` so the second function will enter with the value of x=2 `is_hamming_numbers(2)==True:`
so you have the out put you're having if you want to change it try it this way

```
def hamming_numbers_sequence(x):
print('%s'%x,end=' ')
if x==1:
    return 1
hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1)
if is_hamming_numbers(x)==True:
    // do what ever you want here
```

Comment: I understand that the function hamming_numbers_sequence(x - 1) will repeat itself, but can't wrap my head around the output, if it repeated itself until giving the output of 2 (or looped through), then how come it can still give 3 4 5 6 8 9 10?

Comment: it's all about where you put your print (before entering the sequence or after it),try to compile your code by hand you will understand it better